# Deseralize Vector.<String> from ByteArray

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

I got this situation:

```
var vector:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
vector.push("uno");
vector.push("dos");
vector.push("tres");

var serializer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
serializer.writeObject(vector);
serializer.position = 0;

var vector2:Vector.<String> = serializer.readObject();
trace(vector2[0]);
trace(vector2[1]);
trace(vector2[2]);
```

When the code reach the `trace(vector2[0]);` sentence i got this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert __AS3__.vec::Vector.<Object>@16820d01 to __AS3__.vec.Vector.<String>.
```

Now, if i call `registerClassAlias("com.some.alias", String)` before declare the `vector` variable the code executes without problem.

Why the call to `registerClassAlias()` is needed in this case?

Comment: It's been along time since I ran into a similar issue, but iirc objects deserialized from a `ByteArray` are always returned as untyped `Object` objects. I don't think that you can make it work without `registerClassAlias()` in that case. If you have a custom class you want to [de]serialize you can add the [RemoteClass] [metatag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html) to provide the required type information.

Comment: Thanks for you replay. Where can i find more info about "iirc objects"? Cannot find anything in google...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, "iirc" = "if I remember correctly". Have you checked the docs of [`ByteArray#readObject()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#readObject%28%29) and [`registerClassAlias()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias%28%29)?

Comment: Jaja. Thanks for the "iirc" definition. I will search a little bit more dipper about this topic. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

the writeObject() and readObject() methods respectively write(encode) and return a generic (untyped) *Object* typed objects.

so typing your vector2 as a Vector.< String > will cause the error you get while typing it as a Vector.< Object > or even not typing it at all should work ; in this case an Object will be returned:

```
var vector:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();//Object
vector.push( 'abc' );
vector.push( 123 );
vector.push( { foo:"bar" } );

var serializer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
serializer.writeObject(vector);
serializer.position = 0;

var vector2:Object = serializer.readObject();// NB: readObject returns an Object
trace( 'vector2 is a Object ?', vector2 is Object );//true
trace( 'vector2 is a Vector.<Object> ?', vector2 is Vector.<Object> );//true but see below

trace( vector2[0], 'is a String ?', vector2[0] is String );//abc is a String ? true
trace( vector2[1], 'is a Number ?', vector2[1] is Number );//123 is a Number ? true  ( int and uints are Number )
trace( vector2[2] );//[object Object] untyped object
trace( 'vector2[2].foo => ', vector2[2].foo );// vector2[2].foo =>  bar
trace( 'vector2[2].bar => ', vector2[2].bar );// vector2[2].bar =>  undefined
```

the funny thing is that Vector.< Number > are also typed back correctly when read back while all other types fail are casted as Objects comment / uncomment the vector declarations below to see how it is typed after decoding.

```
//correctly typed
var vector:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();
vector.push( 'abc', 123, { foo:"bar" } );

//var vector:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>();
//vector.push( 123, 456, 789 );

//generic Objects instead
//var vector:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
//vector.push( "a", "b", "c" );

//var vector:Vector.<Function> = new Vector.<Function>();
//vector.push( function a():*{}, function b():*{}, function c():*{} );

//var vector:Vector.<Boolean> = new Vector.<Boolean>();
//vector.push( true, false, true );

var serializer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
serializer.writeObject(vector);
serializer.position = 0;

var vector2:* = serializer.readObject();
trace( 'vector2 is a Object ?', vector2 is Object );//true
trace( 'vector2 is a Vector.<Object> ?', vector2 is Vector.<Object> );
trace( 'vector2 is a Vector.<Number> ?', vector2 is Vector.<Number> );
trace( 'vector2 is a Vector.<String> ?', vector2 is Vector.<String> );
trace( 'vector2 is a Vector.<Function> ?', vector2 is Vector.<Function> );
trace( 'vector2 is a Vector.<Boolean> ?', vector2 is Vector.<Boolean> );
```

I don't know exactly why Numbers also make it, I don't know much about serialization though...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a good example of the situation. I'm start thinking that no one know much about this topic...